Python Tkinter Grid Column width Not expanding need First row not Scorallable
I have three column with scrollbar and it needs to be expand and it should be stretched the window size but i am unable to increase the column width according to the screen size and i need top first row should need to stable that is like heading. the code is below
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TEST")
root.geometry("800x600")

frame=ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

frame3s = ttk.Frame(canvas)
frame3s.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

RCnt = 0
DataRow = {}
LabCnt = 0;
for gh in range(40):
   DataRow[LabCnt] = ttk.Label(frame3s, text=LabCnt, font=("Arial", 16, "bold"),cursor="hand2", justify=tk.CENTER,relief="solid")
   DataRow[LabCnt].grid(row=RCnt, column=0, sticky='ew')
   LabCnt += 1
   DataRow[LabCnt] = ttk.Label(frame3s, text=LabCnt, font=("Arial", 16, "bold"),cursor="hand2", justify=tk.CENTER,relief="solid")
   DataRow[LabCnt].grid(row=RCnt, column=1, sticky='ew')
   LabCnt += 1
   DataRow[LabCnt] = ttk.Label(frame3s, text=LabCnt, font=("Arial", 16, "bold"),cursor="hand2", justify=tk.CENTER,relief="solid")
   DataRow[LabCnt].grid(row=RCnt, column=2, sticky='ew')
   LabCnt += 1
   RCnt += 1
   frame3s.columnconfigure(gh, weight=1)
   frame3s.rowconfigure(gh, weight=1)

frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame3s, anchor="nw")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

def _on_mousewheel(event):
   canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")
canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)
while True:
   root.update()

please guide me to achieve expanded column width according to the screen size

You can set the width of frame3s to the same as the width of canvas inside the callback of event <Configure> on canvas.

@acw1668 can you please give me more detail

@acw1668     frame3s.bind("", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=500,height=500))   is that correct

@acw1668  it is not working

If you want to expand the columns to fit the canvas width, you need to:

save the item ID of canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame3s, ...)
set the width of frame3s to the same as that of canvas inside the callback of event <Configure> on canvas using canvas.itemconfig()
set weight=1 on column 0 to 2 using frame3s.columnconfigure()

Below is the updated code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TEST")
root.geometry("800x600")

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

frame3s = ttk.Frame(canvas)
frame3s.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

RCnt = 0
DataRow = {}
LabCnt = 0;
for gh in range(40):
   DataRow[LabCnt] = ttk.Label(frame3s, text=LabCnt, font=("Arial", 16, "bold"), cursor="hand2", justify=tk.CENTER, relief="solid")
   DataRow[LabCnt].grid(row=RCnt, column=0, sticky='ew')
   LabCnt += 1
   DataRow[LabCnt] = ttk.Label(frame3s, text=LabCnt, font=("Arial", 16, "bold"), cursor="hand2", justify=tk.CENTER, relief="solid")
   DataRow[LabCnt].grid(row=RCnt, column=1, sticky='ew')
   LabCnt += 1
   DataRow[LabCnt] = ttk.Label(frame3s, text=LabCnt, font=("Arial", 16, "bold"), cursor="hand2", justify=tk.CENTER, relief="solid")
   DataRow[LabCnt].grid(row=RCnt, column=2, sticky='ew')
   LabCnt += 1
   RCnt += 1

# expand column 0 to 2 to fill the width of the frame
frame3s.columnconfigure((0,1,2), weight=1)

frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# save the item ID of frame3s
frame_id = canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame3s, anchor="nw")

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

def _on_mousewheel(event):
   canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")

canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)

# set width of frame3s to the same as that of the canvas
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.itemconfig(frame_id, width=e.width))

root.mainloop()  # using .mainloop() instead of while loop

